# Access DB update one table with value from another

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to update all records in one table with the values found in another table.

I've tried many versions of the same basic query and always get the same error message:

> Operation must use an updateable
>   query.

Any thoughts on why this query won't work in Access DB?

```
UPDATE inventoryDetails as idet
SET idet.itemDesc = 
(
    SELECT bomItemDesc
    FROM BOM_TEMPLATES as bt
    WHERE bt.bomModelNumber = idet.modelNumber
)
```

also tried this because I realized that since the second table has multiple model number records for each modelnumber - and I only need the first description from the first record found for each model number.

```
UPDATE inventoryDetails as idet
SET idet.item_desc = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 bomItemDescription 
    FROM BOM_TEMPLATES as bt
    WHERE bt.bomModelNumber = idet.modelNumber
)
```

...still getting the same error though.

Comment: Joins are always better as a starting point than a subquery in Access/Jet because they are better optimized (though many subqueries are well-optimized -- just not all types of them).

Comment: The failure message, "Operation must use an updateable query" may sound a little odd; I mean, the (sub)query isn't the part that is being updated, right? What you need to understand is that in Access-speak all SQL DML is referred to as a 'query' e.g. you get folk saying seeming oxymoron such as 'an update query' when they are referring to an update SQL *statement*.

Comment: ...and such folk are not really at fault: the Access documentation encourages this by using such terminology throughout e.g. 'append query' to mean INSERT INTO *statement*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use a join

```
UPDATE inventoryDetails 
INNER JOIN BOM_TEMPLATES ON inventoryDetails.modelNumber = BOM_TEMPLATES.bomModelNumber 
SET inventoryDetails.itemDesc = [bomItemDesc];
```

Comment: Thanks.
I think I was doing UPDATE, SET, INNER JOIN (in that order).

Answer (score 4):

`Any thoughts on why this query won't work in Access DB`?

The answer is, because ACE/Jet SQL syntax is not SQL-92 compliant (even when in its ANSI-92 Query Mode!).

I'm assuming yours is a scalar subquery. This construct is simply not supported by ACE/Jet.

ACE/Jet has its own quirky and flawed `UPDATE..JOIN` syntax, flawed because the engine doesn't force the `JOIN`ed values to be scalar and it is free to silently use an arbitrary value. It is different again from SQL Server's own UPDATE..JOIN syntax but at least SQL Server supports the Standard scalar subquery as an alternative. ACE/Jet forces you to either learn its quirky non-portable ways or to use an alternative SQL product.

Sorry to sound negative: the ACE/Jet engine is a great piece of software but UPDATE syntax is absolutely fundamental and the fact it hasn't been changed since the SQL-92 Standard really show its age.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
update idet
SET idet.itemDesc = bt.bomItemDesc
from inventoryDetails as idet
     inner join BOM_TEMPLATES as bt
          on bt.bomModelNumber = idet.modelNumber
```

This is how I would write it for SQL server.  Hope Access understands the same command.

Comment: Access hangs starting with the FROM portion.  I had tried a number of versions similar to this.