# where statement in Access 2007-2010 sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, where-clause

I am trying to pull data from one table into a database set up, by getting it to match the product codes then pull the data form the table field into the database field.

I have the below statement, but when I try to run it I get an error saying "Syntax error in Update statement" and it then highlights the where part which I'm guessing has a mistake in it, as I am new to this I don't know what is is.

```
UPDATE [Raw material reg info].[SAP Material Number] 
SET [Sheet1].[SAP Material Number] 
WHERE [Raw material reg info].[CMC Part Code] LIKE [Sheet1].[CMC Part Code];
```

Comment: Please post some sample data from both tables.

Comment: What do you want to set `SET [Sheet1].[SAP Material Number]` to?

Comment: You need to set a value, e.g. `SET [Sheet1].[SAP Material Number] = 12345`

Comment: Okay I'm trying to import the value of the SAP Material Number into the database from the table, when the corresponding CMC Part Code of both the database and the table are the same. Sorry if I haven't explained very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your query and your description, I think this is what you really want. I may be completely wrong, but I can only assume that you want to update the value of the `[SAP Material Number]` field in the `[Raw material reg info]` table where you find a matching `[CMC Part Code]` in the imported `[Sheet1]` data.

```
UPDATE 
    [Raw material reg info]
SET
    [SAP Material Number] = [Sheet1].[SAP Material Number]
FROM
    [Sheet1]
INNER JOIN
    [Raw material reg info] ON [Sheet1].[CMC Part Code] = [Raw material reg info].[CMC Part Code]
```

**Edit:**

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787219/3130094), the syntax for Access is slightly different for the above query. Try this:

```
UPDATE 
    [Raw material reg info]
INNER JOIN
    [Sheet1] ON [Raw material reg info].[CMC Part Code] = [Sheet1].[CMC Part Code]
SET
    [Raw material reg info].[SAP Material Number] = [Sheet1].[SAP Material Number]
```

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do, I just tried the solution you put in but I got the following error "Syntx error (missing operator in query expression '[Sheet1].[SAP Material Number] FROM [Sheet1] INNER JOIN [Raw material reg info] ON [Sheet1].[CMC Part Code] = [Raw material reg info].[CMC Part Code]'.

Comment: @user3930153 - Please try my edited query and let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [Raw material reg info].[SAP Material Number] 
SET [Sheet1].[SAP Material Number] = *Need to specifiy what you want this value to be *
WHERE [Raw material reg info].[CMC Part Code] LIKE [Sheet1].[CMC Part Code];
```

Comment: I can't see much point in `LIKE [Sheet1].[CMC Part Code];` when there is no wild card.

Comment: @Fionnuala I'm just helping out based on the query that was given and the main reason why the query failed. Yes you are right, they should be using a wild card

Comment: I'm not really very good at it I, could onyl feed so much on ms access help site.