# Using an UPDATE and JOIN together in a single statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep getting errors on this statement I am writing and was wondering if anyone could help. I have two tables. Table A and Table B. I would like to update Table A with the values from Table B when two IDs match up.

Currently my code looks like:

```
UPDATE [Table A]

SET [Table A].[Column 1]='value', [Table A].[Column 2]='value2', [Table A].[Column 3]='value3'

INNER JOIN [Table B]

ON [Table A].[Column 1] = [Table B].[Column 1] AND [Table B].[Column 2];
```

But I keep returning a syntax error that I can't identify.

Comment: we cant identify it either as you haven't included the error!

Comment: What is `[Table A].[Table 3]='value3'` supposed to mean?

Comment: In your WHERE clause there should be sth after [Table B].[Column 2]

Comment: what exactly is an sth?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/787219/1592756) for a very similar question. And what @sqluser means is that you're also missing the comparison of `[Table B].[Column 2]`- unless it's a boolean column.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `FROM` clause before your `INNER JOIN`. Joining works the same on `SELECT`, `UPDATE` OR `DELETE`.  Try it like this:

```
UPDATE [Table A]
SET [Table A].[Column 1]='value', [Table A].[Column 2]='value2', [Table A].[Column 3]='value3'
FROM [Table A]
INNER JOIN [Table B]
ON [Table A].[Column 1] = [Table B].[Column 1] AND [Table B].[Column 2];
```

(Untested, but it should do the job)

Comment: I attempted this as well but I received a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression. It states it between the end of my SET statement and the beginning of my FROM statement.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in T-Sql. Access syntax seems to be different.

Answer (score 0):

This will update values from the source table (S) into the target table (T)

```
UPDATE T
SET T.COLUMNA = S.COLUMNA, T.COLUMNB = S.COLUMNB
FROM TARGET T
INNER JOIN SOURCE S ON T.IDCOLUMN = S.IDCOLUMN
WHERE
 S.FILTERCOLUMN = 'FILTERVALUE'
```

However, you may want to consider using a merge statement instead if your scenario calls for it

```
MERGE TARGETTABLE T
USING SOURCETABLE S
    ON S.IDCOLUMN = T.IDCOLUMN
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET COLUMNA = S.COLUMNA, COLUMNB = S.COLUMNB
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(COLUMNA, COLUMNB) VALUES (S.COLUMNA, S.COLUMNB)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: I would have usually used a merge statement but sadly T-SQL doesn't work in access as much as I wish it would haha but thanks for the advice!