# MS Access SQL: Update Join Query with Sum from Another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update the "Price" field of a table named "Products" in this example with the "Quantity" field from another table called "OrderDetails. I use t as a temporary table to store my query results from OrderDetails, then INNER JOIN the two tables (p and t). I'm still getting error. I validated the query piece (SELECT ...... GROUP BY ProductID) works. It's the UPDATE that is throwing error. Any thought?

```
    UPDATE p
    SET Price = t.sumQuan
    FROM Products AS p
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) sumQuan
        FROM OrderDetails
        GROUP BY ProductID 
    ) t
    ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access DB update one table with value from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787186/access-db-update-one-table-with-value-from-another)

Comment: @xQbert The error I received is Syntax error in UPDATE statement which I cannot figure out. I read a few topics around this on Stackoverflow and I still don't know where I did wrong. If someone can help me with some pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just a syntax variance with Access vs other RDBMS?

```
UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) sumQuan
            FROM OrderDetails
            GROUP BY ProductID 
           ) t
  ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID;
SET Price = t.sumQuan
```